…,If not less so
what's the meaning of the phrase(in italics) below?

I have pretensions to be a composer, and hope to be as successful a composer as Anthony Burgess, if not less so.
(The Guardian)
Every Tuesday Lionel would put on a jacket and tie and go down to the seniors’ center to play a couple of games. Unfortunately, as far as games go, chess is about as conducive to social interaction as soli-taire is, if not less so.
(Book: Emotional First Aid, Guy Winch, Phd)


Please edit to tell: do you already know how phrases "if not more/less" etc. work, and are just curious about these two cases? The answer will be different if it needs to explain the phrase itself.

Burgess was (according to the internet) a fairly successful composer, with over 250 published musical pieces. He's obviously better known as a novelist, but Iain Banks comparison to Burgess is with an author known to be a prolific composer.

@AndyBonner I don't know how they work. I would be much appreciated, if you explain.  I first read it in Guy Winch's book(second sentence). Then when I searched it in Google, I found it in 'The Guardian' newspaper (first sentence).

I borrow Michael's definition: if not less so means as small as something stated or possibly even smaller or lesser.
In (2), we are comparing chess with an activity not conducive to social interaction; there's a negative sense.  With if not less so, the paragraph means Lionel's type of activity (playing chess) doesn't have much scope in social interaction; it's at most the same as soli-taire but possibly worse.
(1) We can debate and have different opinions about Anthony Burgess' accomplishment in music.
Anthony Burgess
Let's interpret from context.  The writer's use of if not less so shows that Anthony Burgess was viewed not as a great musician. This is strange when read with as successful a composer as, which seems positive. For a positive light, more should be used:
I have pretensions to be a composer, and hope to be as successful a composer as Anthony Burgess, if not more so.
It's quite hard to use if not less so within the context expressed in (1).  I give a different example:
This fellow can write just a few simple tunes and will probably end up like Anthony Burgess, if not less so.

The statement about "Anthony Burgess, if not less so" seems like a complicated joke. The author starts out saying they have hopes of being a composer, and by the end implies that they do not think they are a good composer.
